# "Running pod install..." infinitely

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to run my app flutter App on IOS Simulator but it says "running pod install..." infinitely

I tried to find a solution but couldn't find any.

Here is my pod file which was automatically generated by cocoa pod:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

The expected result was "The app should run on IOS simulator soon" but it's stuck on "running pod install..."
And then gives the following error:
Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Answer (score 14):

Delete the **`podfile.lock`** file from iOS folder after that go to ios folder and run a below command

```
Pod install
```

It will install all the packages which are in your podfile.

Also, you need to set the target platform. Stay in the iOS folder and run below command

```
open Runner.xcworkspace
```

then your app will be open in XCode. Click on the "Runner" and set your target platform to 8.0. I fix my iOS build issue using this hope this will work for you.

Comment: Here is the error message:
!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods:

- `geolocator` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Runner`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.

Comment: Are you using any library for geolocation?

Comment: No, I am using flutter plugin and I think the issue due to unspecified swift version. I digging into the issue to find out a solution.

Answer (score 7):

use a terminal.
go to your ios folder
run
`pod install --verbose`
you will see what is going on

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing on a recent M1 Mac with Apple Silicon, you may need an additional command after installing Cocoapods found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Developing-with-Flutter-on-Apple-Silicon).

```
sudo gem install ffi
```